# I need a clarification for custom functions in C

Tags: c, cs50

I'm taking the CS50 class week 1 and I made the code work but I don't understand the custom functions part

```
void cat (int n)
```

I know that `cat` is your desired name for your function.
In my own understanding the code inside the parenthesis is the input that your custom function is taking (please correct me if my understanding is wrong)
but what I do not understand totally is the first word of the custom functions code like why is it `void` not `int`.

I would love it it you explained it in a much simpler English since English or programming vocabulary is pretty small atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function format:

```
xxxxx yyyyy(zzzzz)
{
    /* code */
    return something;
}
```

`xxxxx` is the function return type. `void` means that function does not return anything to the caller.

`yyyyy` is the function name.

`zzzzz` are the function parameters. `void` means that function does not take any parameters. Parameters are separated by a comma. Parameter definition consists of type and parameter name.

examples:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
     return x + y;
}
```

the function `add` taking two integers as parameters and returning int

> I do not understand totally is the first word of the custom functions
> code like why is it void not int.

Programmer decided that function `cat` will not return anything

Comment: Hey man thank you for organizing things and making it clear for someone who is totally new to all of this hahaha, Thank you for being generous with your time, I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, "void" is the return value of the function.  In this case, the function is not defined to return a value and would therefor not have a "return" statement with a value.

Edit: But as pointed out below in a comment, it can have a "return" statement without a value.

Comment: The function certainly *can* have a `return;` statement (for example in a conditional statement, to return before any other processing is done) but it can not return any value.

Comment: ohhh straight to the point, thanks for this man!

Answer (score 1):

```c
void cat (int n); // note the semicolon
```

This is a forward declaration of a function named `cat` that takes one `int` named `n` as an input parameter. It's declared `void` which means that the function does not return anything.

The definition of `cat` could look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h> // needed for printf etc.

void cat (int n) {
    printf("the cat is %d years old\n", n);   // note: using `n` here
    // return; // not needed since the function is `void`
}
```

---

Forward declaration are made if you need to resolve circular dependencies:

```c
void foo(int x) { if (x==1) bar(x+1); } // calls `bar`
void bar(int x) { if (x==1) foo(x+1); } // calls `foo`
```

This should not compile because when the compiler processes `foo()`, `bar()` is unknown. A forward declaration of `bar()` before `foo()` solves it:

```c
void bar(int x); // forward declaration saves the situation
void foo(int x) { if (x==1) bar(x+1); }
void bar(int x) { if (x==1) foo(x+1); }
```

Forward declarations can also be used to declare all functions defined in the file at the top of the file and implement (define) them later. The list of functions then works as a sort of index of all the functions in the file. It's a matter of coding style. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// forward declarations of all functions (except main):
void cat (int n);

// program entry point:
int main (void) {
    cat(12);       // calling cat with the argument 12 (an `int`)
    return 0;      // not strictly required when returning from main
}

// all the definitions follows:
void cat (int n) {
    printf("the cat is %d years old\n", n); // prints: the cat is 12 years old
}
```

Comment: Looking at it is kinda overwhelming, Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question, I love how detailed it is and the explanation to the little things, I really want to understand what and why a certain code is there and you delivered it perfectly. Thank you Ted, I might ask more dumb questions here in stack overflow as I continue to learn hahaha hopefully I wont get unmotivated, I kinda wasted a lot of years in my life doing nothing and I'm already 24 now still trying to survive and fight my laziness hahaha!

Comment: @Nomer You are welcome! Hope you stick with programming. It's fun :-)

Answer (score 0):

The term has fallen out of use, but it may be more clear to (silently) regard the example given as a 'subroutine'. Whatever is done by `cat()` is to be done, but the perhaps many lines of fiddley code would distract from the flow of processing where `cat()` has been called. Putting those lines of code into a 'subroutine' means that the main body of code can be shorter and easier to understand.

Another benefit of a 'subroutine' is that the same processing can be done (called) from multiple locations without duplicating lines of code.

Here's a snippet of a contrived and trivial example I hope makes this plain. The task is to count from 0 to 'n', printing every so often, and then printing the final value reached:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// 'Subroutine' that provides some service
void out( int n ) {
    /* this represents what could be many lines of code */
    printf( "Have reached %d\n", n );
}

int main() {
    int maxVal = 23; // some ceiling value

    /* somewhere in the body of code */
    int i = 0; // initial condition

    out( i ); // output initial value

    do {
        i = i + 1; // processing

        // output if a threshold reached
        if( (i / 5) * 5 == i )
            out( i );

    } while( i < maxVal );

    out( i ); // output final value

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Have reached 0
Have reached 5
Have reached 10
Have reached 15
Have reached 20
Have reached 23
```

Comment: Woaaah I haven't encountered this situation yet in cs50 but I learned something new which is nicee! Yeah btw do you have any tips in learning cs50, I kinda became too conscious that I'll miss something despite the lecturer telling me to take it as face value.

Comment: @Nomer Tips? Not really... Sometimes it helps to just doodle boxes and arrows and think about single boxes and stacks of boxes and loops (iterations)... The more you play with the ideas, the more comfortable they will become... Everything seems tough at first... Persevere... :-)